# Best browser to embed an interpreter in

Tags: c++, python, browser, scripting, interpreter

I have a decision to make. A few of them actually, and as the stack overflow community has never failed me before I am going to trust it once more.

I've always found the idea of running another scripting language in the browser fascinating. To be more specific: python or ruby. To be even more specific: python. I am aware of the fact that nothing could replace JavaScript due to the inertia that JavaScript has, especially **recently**. I'm also aware that python can not be sandboxed properly in a lifetime worth of coding. But still if I could just see one simple script execute on a browser, running a native interpreter(no Silverlight) I could die in piece.

My true quest is **to find the best solution for integrating a python interpreter into a browser**.

I assume that would be to take a really lightweight or/and modular open-source browser, take the CPython interpreter and just start integrating.

And since stack overflow is about specific questions, based on my assumptions, here is the question: Is there a lightweight open-source browser, that is modular enough to make my goal easier?

Comment: Its really simple to embed an interpreter, but it is extremely dangerous (malicious code attempts).

Comment: Do you want to have access to the DOM via some global/builtin object(s) the way JS does?

Comment: I ask for advice from exactly the people who find it simple. I tought all browsers provice access to the DOM? They certainly need to at least build a DOM tree right? If there is no API exposing it, it wouldn't be hard to patch the sourcecode a little and expose one.

Comment: If you think it wouldn't be hard to add that in, you've obviously never hacked on, or even embedded, a web browser… They are incredibly complicated beasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

> Is there a lightweight open-source browser, that is modular enough to make my goal easier?

Not really, no. WebKit is about as close as you're going to get, but it's not very lightweight, and much of the functionality you want isn't exposed through the simple interfaces. (Plus, the DOM that WebKit exposes is the strict W3C DOM; all the stuff that Safari and Chrome do to render not-quite-standard real-world pages isn't accessible this way.) Looking at how Chromium ripped out the JS engine and replaced it with another might help, at which point you might be able to build the same API as a wrapper around CPython, but it's not going to be easy.

Gecko is very modular, and used to be easy to plug things into, but that's no longer true in recent versions. Unless you're willing to use XULRunner 1.9.2, you'll have a lot of work cut out for you.

Everything else open source is just way too weak to display modern web pages, unless you want a text-only browser… and in that case, lynx and links are both monolithic, so the only option I can think of is emacs w3-mode.

---

However, there's a much easier way to go about this: just plug a Python engine into a ready-made browser.

NPAPI (everything but IE) and ActiveX (IE) are both powerful enough to do what you want: expose custom objects to the browser as `<object>`s, and access the DOM from your code. And embedding CPython isn't that hard. Using [`FireBreath`](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+Home) instead of direct NPAPI and ActiveX is even easier. I believe there are at least two projects that let you write FireBreath plugins in Python and/or embed a generic CPython interpreter into a FireBreath plugin, which may be all you need, out of the box.

For Gecko, there's also PyXPCOM. You can build a XUL extension with an embedded CPython interpreter, and access the browser via XPCOM, then use [PyDOM](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/PyDOM) to build JS-style DOM globals on top of that XPCOM interface. And I *know* this one has already been done; I'm pretty sure [PyXPCOMExt](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/) is a dead project, and it probably won't even build against anything newer than XULRunner 1.9.2, but it should serve as an example (assuming you know all the many and intricate ways that modern XPCOM differs from the old days…).

---

Another option is to just embed a browser engine as-is, and use its embedding APIs together with some JS proxy/stub code to fake running embedded Python scripts on the page. PyQt, the Cocoa WebKit bindings, etc. can all do this; Apple has examples of the kind of code you'd need to get started their ObjC WebKit documentation.

---

Meanwhile, if you don't need the browser to be open source, IE has hooks to embed different scripting engines, and a default IronPython install hooks into it, and knows how to act inside a DOM. So, a local page with `<script type="text/python" language="python">` just works.

---

Finally, although you didn't want Silverlight… it's also not that hard to build a Python interpreter in Python, compile it to Silverlight, and have a full interpreter in the browser that way. The only hard part is getting the IronPython stdlib in there somewhere. Or… there are at least two commercial products that do all of this for you so you don't have to.

---

See [WebBrowserProgramming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming) on the Python Wiki for more, although much of it is probably out of date.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through all the options you suggested and choose for myself. Just one more question. As my goal is not to make the browser actually usable, I can settle with old engines. Which version of Gecko are you referring to?

Comment: @Slytael: You probably want either Gecko 1.9.0 (aka Firefox/XULRunner 3.0) or Gecko 1.9.2/3.6 (aka Firefox/XULRunner 3.6). If you want to go that way, the [`pyxpcomext`](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org) project, or one of the offshoots linked from that page, may just work out of the box, and, together with `PyDOM`, give you everything you need.